# Copy text only from web page without html into Gmail body email

Tags: html, css, gmail, markup

The user wants to be able to copy text only directly into gmail email body without its inner html and styles. is there anyway to do that?

copying into address bar or any other place works fine but to the mail body, it doesn't.

I still want to copy so user-select css attribute will not help me.

I googled that but I couldn't find a good solution for that, and I'm not experienced  in front-end tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
(<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> for Macs).

Comment: thanks, it works, but I can't ask the user to click three buttons instead of ctrl+v the usual move for that which they can do without thinking. espically that they're not IT.